# Twitter request returns "message": "Invalid or expired token", "code": 89 So which is it INVALID OR EXPIRED?

Tags: actionscript-3, twitter, oauth, air, oauth-2.0

WTF!
Building an Adobe AIR twitter search appliance using Application only auth. 
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth
I can correctly obtain my Bearer token, but ALL requests result in

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 86
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Wed, 19 Feb 2014 16:08:13 UTC
server: tfe
strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519

{"errors":[{"message":"Invalid or expired token","code":89}]}
```

So, what is it, INVALID or EXPIRED?

I notice that in my Response Headers for my Bearer token there is an 'expires' header with a value of Tue, 31 Mar 1981 05:00:00 GMT
Does this apply to the bearer token itself?

These ambiguous error messages are giving me (and I'm sure lots of other developers) TONS OF GRIEF!

How do we debug requests with bearer tokens when we receive this message???

Please help...anyone!!!!!!! In Oauth hell!

Answer (score 0):

Are you stuck at step 3 of the process from https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth?

See also the common error cases, seems your token is invalid.

For further help, we suggest using https://dev.twitter.com/discussions to post your issue, we infrequently come here on SO, but monitor questions on our developer site daily.

Comment: yes step 3 and posted on twitter discussions,but more traffic here, my entire RAW request above

Comment: common error cases: Using an incorrect or revoked bearer token. Fine. So now I must determine whether it is 'incorrect' or revoked. There MUST be a better way to check validity of Bearer tokens, whether before or after base64 encoding! All I've done for my Authorization header is "Authorization", "Bearer "+ <base64encoded bearerToken>.

Comment: I also notice in my cookie 3 values are returned and set external_referer
_twitter_sess
guest_id. Does this seem correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
GET /1.1/search/tweets.json?q=sochi HTTP/1.1
Host: api.twitter.com
Accept-Language: en-us
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/533.19.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) AdobeAIR/3.9
Accept: */*
Referer: app:/TweetMasher700.swf
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
x-flash-version: 11,9,900,117
Cookie: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxx==
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I was able to fix the the issue doing this:

```
consumer_key = "put here your API key"
consumer_secret = "put here your API secret"

access_token = "put here your access token" ##remember to put the "-" that separete your owener ID and your token
access_token_secret = "put here your token secret"

auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(access_token, access_token_secret, consumer_key, consumer_secret)
```

Very important to separate the consumer key and secret from the token access and secreat, becuase many people mix up the authorization and the access token, making twitter plataform deny your access.